# How to fix the reg expression for matching CJK characters and grouping in vim?

Tags: regex, vim, regex-group

```
hello world     世界你好
```

I want to change it into below in vim.
It was tested that `[\u4e00-\u9fff]` can match chinese character in vim .

```
世界你好;hello world
```

Why the expression can't do it?

```
:%s/^\([a-w]\+\)\s\+\([\u4e00-\u9fff].\+\)$/\2;\1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex instead: `^\([a-z ]\+\)\([\u4e00-\u9fff]\+\)$`

```
:%s/^\([a-z ]\+\)\([\u4e00-\u9fff]\+\)$/\2;\1
```

Comment: To change [a-w] into [a-z] ,it is so simple.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature there is a space after the z, it is the missing bit in your regular expression. try just adding a space in your original regular expression